# Using Castle Dynamic Proxy - Possible to control and/or remove interceptors

Tags: c#, reflection, castle-windsor, interceptor, castle-dynamicproxy

I made a simple test of the Castle Dynamic Proxy library:

```
public class Printer
{
    public virtual void Write(string msg)
    {
        Console.Write(msg); 
    }
}

public class CastleDynamicProxy
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        ProxyGenerator generator = new ProxyGenerator();

        Printer logger = generator.CreateClassProxy<Printer>(new TestInterceptor());

        logger.Write("Hello, World!"); 
    }
}
```

Now in my interceptor I want to time the function, but its causing a StackOverflowException because I am calling the target method inside the Intercept method, causing an infinite loop:

```
public class TestInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
       var accessor = invocation.Proxy as IProxyTargetAccessor;

       MethodInfo target = accessor.DynProxyGetTarget().GetType().GetMethod("Write"); 

       var s = Stopwatch.StartNew(); 

       target.Invoke(invocation.InvocationTarget, invocation.Arguments);

       s.Stop(); 
    }
}
```

Is there anyway around this, either by 1) stopping the interceptions process altogether, or 2) removing my interceptor after I have used it for what I need, before getting into an infinite loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure that's what you want to do?  I've created a timing interceptor as well to see if a method call (such as a DB query) exceeds a threshold, and if so to log it.

Instead of manually invoking the target, just use `invocation.Proceed()` to tell it to go ahead with the intercepted call.

My code looks like this:

```
        public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
        {
            var timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            // i think you want this to proceed with the invocation...
            invocation.Proceed();

            timer.Stop();

            // check if threshold is exceeded
            if (timer.Elapsed > _threshold)
            {
                // log it to logger of choice
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, if I understand correctly -- invocation.Proceed() will always invoke the original method being intercepted, right?

Comment: Yep, that's the ticket!  Interceptors can be quite handy.  I have several ones we use in my company, but my favorite two log the duration of a method, one that logs duration of method if it exceeds a threshold (we like to know if any of our DB calls exceed 2000 ms for example), and one useful for debugging which logs all input parameters and return values from the methods intercepted as xml to the log if log level == debug